# Mysql2 Installation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby

When i try to run the command `rake db:create:all` it's giving the following error:

```
rake db:create
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "database"=>"db/test", "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "host"=>"localhost", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}, charset: , collation:
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "database"=>"db/development", "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "host"=>"localhost", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}, charset: , collation:
```

Comment: Is your MySQL server running?

Comment: More information is needed. Has this worked in the past? If so, what changed? Does the name of the database host and database match your configuration file? Can you connect using `mysql` directly from the command-line using the same credentials? Is `nil` the value you added to the configuration to mask the real password, or is it what is really in the configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the information in config/database.yml correct?  The "db/test" and "db/development" look suspicious for database names.

And never use root access in your programs, even in testing.  Go through the effort to create SQL users and GRANT appropriate access capabilities.

Comment: @Unknown_Guy I'm new to ruby on rails.. i try to connect the mysql database to my application for that i just copied the libmysql.dll file into my ruby bin folder. And i am sure i am not running any sql server..i just changed the gem file and the configuration/db.yml files only

Comment: You need to install the MySql server on your local machine for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

@dary7yl Thank you dary..it's able to creating the tables. The problem is solved by after installing the xamp and run the mysql server. And i also made one change in database.yml file ..i changed the database name from "db/development" to "development"..beacuse the mysql giving me the error when i try to given the database name with "db/name"...Once again thank's man..